# Common tableview for two controllers

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have a project with a `dialerView` and a `contactView`.

`dialerView`:

```
class DialerView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var info = Info()
var filterdCells = [CellInfo]()
@IBOutlet weak var inputNumber: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var callButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var backspaceButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var keypadSubscript: [UILabel]!
@IBOutlet weak var keypad: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var contactList: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    callButton.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    backspaceButton.isEnabled = false

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func dialerButtonOp(_ sender: Any) {
    backspaceButton.isEnabled = true
    let button = sender as! UIButton
    inputNumber.text?.append((button.titleLabel?.text)!)
    switch button.title(for: UIControlState.normal)! {
    case "2",
         "3",
         "4",
         "5",
         "6",
         "7",
         "8" ,
         "9":
        let str = computeFilter()
        filterdCells = info.filterSearch(filter: str)
        contactList.reloadData()
    default:
        print ("\(button.title(for: UIControlState.normal)!) is a non-alphabet associated number")
    }

}
@IBAction func backspace(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if inputNumber.text != nil && inputNumber.text != "" {
        inputNumber.text?.remove(at: (inputNumber.text?.index(before: (inputNumber.text?.endIndex)!))!)
    }
    if inputNumber.text == nil || inputNumber.text == "" {
        backspaceButton.isEnabled = false
        filterdCells.removeAll()
        contactList.reloadData()
    } else {
        let str = computeFilter()
        filterdCells = info.filterSearch(filter: str)
        contactList.reloadData()
    }
}

@IBAction func longPress0Recognizer(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if inputNumber.text == nil || inputNumber.text == "" {
        backspaceButton.isEnabled = true
    }
    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
        inputNumber.text?.append("+")
    }
}

@IBAction func longPressXRecognizer(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
        if backspaceButton.isEnabled {
            inputNumber.text = ""
            backspaceButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}

// Remove + signs from filter string
func computeFilter() -> String {
    let str = inputNumber.text!
    var newstr = String()
    for i in 0..<str.characters.count {
        let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: i)
        if str[index] != "+" {
            newstr.append(str[index])
        }
    }
    return newstr
}

// Conform to delegate and datasource
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if filterdCells.count == 0 {
        return 0
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filterdCells.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    tableView.rowHeight = CGFloat(60)
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ContactCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Contact")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Contact", for: indexPath) as! ContactCell
    cell.nameLabel.text = filterdCells[indexPath.row].name
    cell.numLabel.text = filterdCells[indexPath.row].number
    return cell
}
}
```

`contactView:`

```
class ContactView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate, NewContactDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var editList: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var addressBook: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

var VC: MainViewController? = nil
var showSearchResults = false
var filteredCells = [CellInfo]()

var info = Info()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    info.populateCells()
    if showSearchResults {
        return filteredCells.count
    } else {
        return info.cellInfo.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    tableView.rowHeight = CGFloat(60)
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ContactCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Contact")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Contact", for: indexPath) as! ContactCell
    if showSearchResults {
        cell.nameLabel.text = filteredCells[indexPath.row].name
        cell.numLabel.text = filteredCells[indexPath.row].number
    } else {
        cell.nameLabel.text = info.cellInfo[indexPath.row].name
        cell.numLabel.text = info.cellInfo[indexPath.row].number
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
        let index: Int?
        if showSearchResults == true {
            index = info.names.index(of: filteredCells[indexPath.row].name)
            filteredCells.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        } else {
            index = info.names.index(of: info.cellInfo[indexPath.row].name)
        }
        info.removeContact (index: index!)
        tableView.reloadData()
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.insert) {
        print ("Trying to edit")
    }

}
//Disable deletion capability when not in edit mode
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    if tableView.isEditing {
        return .delete
    } else {
        return .none
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let editContactVC = EditContact(nibName: "EditContact", bundle: nil)
    editContactVC.delegate = self
    editContactVC.index = indexPath.row
    if showSearchResults {
        editContactVC.name = filteredCells[indexPath.row].name
        editContactVC.number = filteredCells[indexPath.row].number
    } else {
        editContactVC.name = info.cellInfo[indexPath.row].name
        editContactVC.number = info.cellInfo[indexPath.row].number

    }
    self.present(editContactVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filteredCells.removeAll()
    filteredCells = info.cellInfo.filter ({ (cell: CellInfo) -> Bool in
        return cell.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
    })

    if searchText != "" {
        showSearchResults = true
    } else {
        showSearchResults = false
    }
    addressBook.reloadData()
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    showSearchResults = true
    searchBar.endEditing(true)
    addressBook.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func NewContact(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let addContactVC = AddContact(nibName: "AddContact", bundle: nil)
    addContactVC.delegate = self
    self.present(addContactVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// Add a new contact
func add_Contact(name: String, num: String) {
    info.addContact(name: name, num: num)
    addressBook.reloadData()
}

// Edit existing contact
func edit_Contact(name: String, num: String, index: Int) {
    let arrayIndex:Int?
    if showSearchResults == true {
        arrayIndex = info.names.index(of: filteredCells[index].name)
        filteredCells[index].name = name
        filteredCells[index].number = num
    } else {
        arrayIndex = info.names.index(of: info.cellInfo[index].name)
    }
    info.editContact(name: name, num: num, index: arrayIndex!)
    addressBook.reloadData()
}

// Edit mode to Delete Cells
@IBAction func EditContactList(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if let text = editList?.title {
        if text == "Edit" {
            VC?.scrollView?.isScrollEnabled = false
            addressBook.isEditing = true
            editList.title = "Done"
        } else {
            VC?.scrollView?.isScrollEnabled = true
            addressBook.isEditing = false
            editList.title = "Edit"
        }
    }
}   
}
```

`Info`:

```
class Info {
var cellInfo = [CellInfo]()
var names = ["R", "R", "S", "P", "M", "V", "M", "S"]
var numbers = ["9830000001", "9830000002", "9830000003", "9830000004",
               "9830000005", "9830000006", "9830000007", "9830000008"]

let dict:[Int: [String]] = [2: ["A", "B", "C"], 3: ["D", "E", "F"], 4: ["G", "H", "I"],
                            5: ["J", "K", "L"], 6: ["M", "N", "O"], 7: ["P", "Q", "R", "S"],
                            8: ["T", "U", "V"], 9: ["W", "X", "Y", "Z"]]

// Compute keypad combinaton for names
func computeNameCode(name: String) -> String {
    var nameCode = ""
    for j in 0..<name.characters.count {
        let index = name.index(name.startIndex, offsetBy: j)
        let ch = name[index]
        //print (ch)
        nameCode.append(findKey(ch: ch))
    }
    return nameCode
}

// Find key value for character
func findKey (ch: Character) -> String {
    for (key, array) in dict {
        if (array.contains(ch.description)) {
            //print ("Key for \(ch) is \(key)")
            return key.description
        }
    }
    return ""
}

func populateCells() {
    cellInfo.removeAll()
    for i in 0..<names.count {
        var objCellInfo = CellInfo ()
        objCellInfo.name = names[i]
        objCellInfo.number = numbers[i]
        objCellInfo.nameCode = computeNameCode(name: names[i].uppercased())
        cellInfo.append(objCellInfo)
    }
    cellInfo.sort(by: sortNames)
}

// func sortNames
func sortNames ( name1: CellInfo, name2: CellInfo ) -> Bool {
    return name1.name.uppercased() < name2.name.uppercased()
}

func filterSearch(filter: String) -> [CellInfo] {
    populateCells()
    return (cellInfo.filter ({ (cell: CellInfo) -> Bool in
        return cell.nameCode.lowercased().contains(filter.lowercased())
    }))
}

func addContact(name: String, num: String) {
    names.append(name)
    numbers.append(num)
}

func editContact(name: String, num: String, index:Int ) {
    names[index] = name
    numbers[index] = num
}

func removeContact(index: Int) {
    names.remove(at: index)
    numbers.remove(at: index)
}
}
```

my struct:

```
struct CellInfo {
    var name:String = ""
    var number:String = ""
    var nameCode:String = ""
}
```

Both of these views are loaded onto a paging enabled scrollView. So the first view loaded is the `DialerView` and on scrolling right, i see the `ContactView`.

What i want to do is use the `namecode` in `ContactView` to filter my results and display them in a UITable in `DialerView` without having to rewrite all the code. What would be the best way to use my `DialerView` UIlabel (named `InputNumber`) as a search parameter for my UItable (named `addressBook`) in `ContactView` and display filtered cells in `DialerView` (in a table placed above the dialer)

What is `namecode`?

`namecode` holds the dialer combination for saved contact names (check `dict` in `ContactView`, that should make things clear).

What I want to achieve:

John would have a namecode of -> 5646. So when I enter 5/56/564/5646 on my `DialerView`, John should be displayed as a pre-saved contact I can call in a UITableView above the dialer

**Edit:** I made a new class called `Info` and added my data and it's manipulation into the class. `DialerView` and `ContactView` both work with an object of `Info` but how do i make them use the **SAME** object to provide data consistency?
Currently if i add a new contact (functionality available in `ContavtView`) it does not show up as a search result on my `DialerView`. It's only reading the predefined data.

Thank you.

Comment: A bit of code review before anything else. `CellInfo.names` is a singular `String`. Don't give it a plural name. Call it `name`, `number`, `nameCode` etc... Also, the properties of `CellInfo` are not being mutated. So make them all `let` and remove the `= ""`

Comment: @Fogmeister Gotcha. Yeah i'll fix those in my files. Thanks for the suggestion!
Also, my name,number and nameCode are indeed mutated. I just omitted that code out as it wasn't required for this question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a UIView type class and in this class, you have to add table view and its delegate/datasource methods. and add protocols(create custom delegate methods) for use whereever you want to add this tableview, means contactview and declairview

**Edit**

**Contact.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Contact;
@protocol ContactTableDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)didSelectRowForContact:(Contact *)contact atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end
@interface ContactTableView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ContactTableDelegate>            delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray                           *tableData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Contact                           *selectedContactForFirstSelectedVC;

- (void)keyboardWillDisplay;
- (void)keyboardwillHide;
- (void)actionRefresh:(UIButton *)button;

@end
```

**Contact.M**

```
#import "ContactTableView.h"
#import "Contact.h"
#import "Utility.h"
#import "FontUtility.h"
#import "StyleDefinitions.h"
#import "AsyncImageView.h"
#import "GetContactsFromDevice.h"
#import "DataHandler.h"
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
#import "FirstSelectedMatchMakeViewController.h"
#import "Constants.h"

@interface ContactTableView () < UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate,ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate > {
    UITableView             *contactTableView;
    NSMutableDictionary     *sections;
    NSArray                 *sectionTitles;
    NSArray                 *indexTitles;
    NSArray                 *searchResults;
    BOOL                    isSearchBarOn;
    UITextField             *searchBar;
}

@end

@implementation ContactTableView
@synthesize tableData;
@synthesize selectedContactForFirstSelectedVC;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:233.0/255.0 green:233.0/255.0 blue:233.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    [self setupViews];
}

- (void)setupViews {

    //Setup Search Bar
    searchBar = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, self.bounds.size.width - 20, 30)];
    searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    searchBar.delegate = self;
    searchBar.background = kImageSearchBG;
    searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
    [self addSubview:searchBar];

    UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    UIImageView *searchImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 8, 14, 14)];
    searchImage.image = kImageSearchIcon;
    paddingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [paddingView addSubview:searchImage];
    searchBar.leftView = paddingView;
    searchBar.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

    contactTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, searchBar.frame.size.height + searchBar.frame.origin.y + 10, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height - searchBar.frame.size.height-20-40)];
    contactTableView.delegate = self;
    contactTableView.dataSource = self;
    contactTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    contactTableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    contactTableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self addSubview:contactTableView];
    contactTableView.sectionIndexColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:105.0/255.0 green:240.0/255.0 blue:174.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [contactTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:243.0/255.0 green:243.0/255.0 blue:243.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

    contactTableView.tableFooterView  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.frame.size.width, 0.0f)];
    contactTableView.tableFooterView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    indexTitles = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z"];

    // Add New and Refresh option
    [self setContactTableOptions];
}

#pragma - 
#pragma - Add New and Refresh Actions

- (void)setContactTableOptions {

    CGSize screenSize          = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    CGFloat currentViewHeight   = screenSize.height - self.frame.origin.y;

    // inserting add new and refresh buttons

    UIButton *buttonAddNew = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, currentViewHeight-40, kScreenSize.width/2-1, 40)];
    [buttonAddNew setTitle:kAddNew forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonAddNew addTarget:self action:@selector(actionAddNew:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [buttonAddNew setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonAddNew.titleLabel setFont:[FontUtility semiBoldFontWithSize:16.0]];
    [buttonAddNew.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [buttonAddNew setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self addSubview:buttonAddNew];

    UIButton *buttonRefresh = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kScreenSize.width/2+1, currentViewHeight-40, kScreenSize.width/2-1, 40)];
    [buttonRefresh setTitle:kRefresh forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonRefresh addTarget:self action:@selector(actionRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [buttonRefresh setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonRefresh.titleLabel setFont:[FontUtility semiBoldFontWithSize:16.0]];
    [buttonRefresh.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [buttonRefresh setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self addSubview:buttonRefresh];
}


- (void)newPersonViewController:(ABNewPersonViewController *)newPersonView didCompleteWithNewPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
    UIViewController *vc = [Utility traverseResponderChainForUIViewController:self];
    [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self actionRefresh:nil];
}


- (void)actionAddNew:(UIButton *)button {
    ABNewPersonViewController *picker   = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];

    UIViewController *vc = [Utility traverseResponderChainForUIViewController:self];
    picker.newPersonViewDelegate        = self;

    UINavigationController *navigation  = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:picker];
    [vc presentViewController:navigation animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)actionRefresh:(UIButton *)button {
    button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [self showLoadingOnWindow];
    [GetContactsFromDevice refreshAllContactsInfo:^(BOOL flag) {
        button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        if ([[Utility traverseResponderChainForUIViewController:self] isKindOfClass:[FirstSelectedMatchMakeViewController class]]) {
            NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.recordID != %d",selectedContactForFirstSelectedVC.recordID];
            self.tableData = [[DataHandler sharedInstance].deviceContactList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
        } else {
            self.tableData = [DataHandler sharedInstance].deviceContactList;
        }
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(hideLoadingView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(hideLoadingView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }];
}

- (void)hideLoadingView {
    [self hideLoadingFromWindow];
}

- (void)setTableData:(NSArray *)aTableData {
    tableData = aTableData;
    [self organizeData];
    searchBar.text = @"";
    isSearchBarOn = false;
    //relaod table instantly
    [contactTableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

}

- (void)setSelectedContactForFirstSelectedVC:(Contact *)aContact {
    selectedContactForFirstSelectedVC = aContact;
}

- (void)organizeData {
    sections = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (Contact *contact in tableData) {
        NSString *c = [[contact.name substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", c]; // if you need case sensitive search avoid '[c]' in the predicate
        NSArray *results = [sections.allKeys filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        if (results.count == 0)
            [sections setValue:[NSMutableArray array] forKey:c];
    }

    for (Contact *contact in tableData) {
        NSString *temp = contact.name;
        [[sections objectForKey:[[temp substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]] addObject:contact];
    }
    sectionTitles = [[sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
}


- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
    //predicate for searching specific data
    NSPredicate *namePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    NSPredicate *emailPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.primaryEmail contains[c] %@", searchText];

    NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[namePredicate, emailPredicate]];
    searchResults = [tableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:compoundPredicate];

    [contactTableView reloadData];
}

- (void)keyboardWillDisplay {
    // write code here for table hight
    contactTableView.frame = CGRectMake(contactTableView.frame.origin.x, contactTableView.frame.origin.y,
                                        contactTableView.frame.size.width,  contactTableView.frame.size.height-215);
}


- (void)keyboardwillHide {

    contactTableView.frame = CGRectMake(contactTableView.frame.origin.x, contactTableView.frame.origin.y,
                                        contactTableView.frame.size.width,  contactTableView.frame.size.height+215);
}

#pragma mark-
#pragma mark- TextField and Search  methods
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    return [textField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (![[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string] isEqualToString:@""]) {
        isSearchBarOn = true;
        [self filterContentForSearchText:[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string] scope:[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]];
    } else {
        isSearchBarOn = false;
        [contactTableView reloadData];
    }
    return YES;
}




#pragma mark-
#pragma mark- Table methods

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (isSearchBarOn)
        return 1;
    return [sectionTitles count];
}
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (isSearchBarOn)
        return nil;

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 22)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:233.0/255.0 green:233.0/255.0 blue:233.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    UILabel *lable = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, tableView.frame.size.width-10,view.frame.size.height)];
    lable.text = [sectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
    [view addSubview:lable];
    return view;
}
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (isSearchBarOn)
        return nil;
    return indexTitles;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    if (isSearchBarOn)
        return 0;
    return [sectionTitles indexOfObject:title];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (isSearchBarOn)
        return [searchResults count];
    return  [[sections valueForKey:[[[sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section]] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kContactCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:kContactCellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243.0/255.0 green:243.0/255.0 blue:243.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
    }

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    UIImageView *cellImg = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *lblCellName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    UILabel *lblCellEmail = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];

    cellImg.layer.cornerRadius     = cellImg.frame.size.width / 2;
    cellImg.layer.borderWidth      = 1.0;
    cellImg.layer.borderColor      = (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor clearColor]);
    cellImg.clipsToBounds          = YES;

    if (isSearchBarOn) {
        Contact *contact = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if (contact.recordID) {

            if (![Utility imageForContactId:contact.recordID]) {
                cellImg.image = kImageUserIcon;
            } else {
                [cellImg setImage:[Utility imageForContactId:contact.recordID]];
            }

        } else {

            if (contact.imageURL.length<=0) {
                cellImg.image = kImageUserIcon;
            } else {
                cellImg.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:contact.imageURL];
            }
        }

        [lblCellName setText:contact.name];
        [lblCellEmail setText:[[contact.email componentsSeparatedByString:@","] firstObject]];

    } else {

        Contact *contact = [[sections valueForKey:[[[sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        if (contact.recordID > 0) {

            if (![Utility imageForContactId:contact.recordID]) {
                cellImg.image = kImageUserIcon;
            } else {
                [cellImg setImage:[Utility imageForContactId:contact.recordID]];
            }
        } else {

            if (contact.imageURL.length<=0) {
                cellImg.image = kImageUserIcon;
            } else {
                cellImg.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:contact.imageURL];
            }
        }

        [lblCellName setText:contact.name];
        [lblCellEmail setText:[[contact.email componentsSeparatedByString:@","] firstObject]];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didSelectRowForContact:atIndexPath:)]) {
        if (isSearchBarOn) {
            [self.delegate didSelectRowForContact:searchResults[indexPath.row] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            [searchBar endEditing:YES];
        } else {
            [self.delegate didSelectRowForContact:[sections objectForKey:sectionTitles[indexPath.section]][indexPath.row] atIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
        searchBar.text = @"";
        [tableView reloadData];
    }

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 88.0;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 22.0;
}

#pragma - 
#pragma - Dealloc Method

- (void)dealloc {

    selectedContactForFirstSelectedVC       = nil;
    contactTableView                        = nil;
    sections                                = nil;
    sectionTitles                           = nil;
    indexTitles                             = nil;
    searchResults                           = nil;
    isSearchBarOn                           = nil;
    searchBar                               = nil;
    tableData                               = nil;

}

@end
```

**Now steps**

- Now you have to add a view on storyboard with contact class.
- Add outlet on viewcontroller where you want to add this table
- And after that, You have to set delegate from where you want to add this table like this:

  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet ContactTableView  *contactTableView;

  self.contactTableView.delegate  = self;

  self.contactTableView.tableData = table_data;

Comment: so I should have a 3rd UIView class that basically has all the tableView functions and delegates in it from `ContactView` and use it's instance to share it between `ContactView` and `DialerView`. Am i understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes, Then you can use this class anywhere in you project

Comment: I have a obj-c code for same. If you want then i will give you, I have done it for same reason and same scenario.

Comment: I see. How different is that from a singleton (as the answer below mentioned)?
And I really appreciate the offer but this is something i want to figure out on my own because i'm really trying to learn Swift better :) If i hit a wall, i will ask for your code for reference <3

Comment: You have no need to do this using a singleton class.

Comment: Yes sure, I will be there for you

Comment: I see. Alright i'll just try to create a new class and restructure my code for now then. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary Ugghh. i've been trying since yesterday. I moved all my data into a 3rd class called `Info` and have my data manipulation functions defined in `Info` itself. I do not know how to make `ContactView` and `DialerView` share the same object of `Info` to have consistent data. Any tips?

Comment: Can you share me your code...actually I am not getting your point.

Comment: @RJ You have created info class but table view methods are available in both classes. So You have to move all table view methods into info class. means, all stuff about table view, moved into info class and create the custom delegate to access these methods. You do not need to add above methods into info class. You have to created info class only for a table because you need to use one table class in many controllers.

Comment: ohhhhhh. i see what you mean. okay. let me try! thanks. sorry for bothering you so much.

Comment: @RJ It's ok. no need to say sorry.

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary would it be possible for you to share you Obj-C code? I think i'll take a look. I am not very good at delegates.

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary OHHHHH. I  see what is going on here, but does this preserve data consistency? So during simulation, when you add a new contact in one view's table (say ViewA),  does it automatically also get added on ViewB's table

Comment: Yes, You have to reload the table from the controller(Controller have the table class outlet,Using this reference, you can reload the table  )

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary That really helps. I need to learn protocols better haha. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the dataSource somewhere that is accessible by both of class (like a singleton class/database/NSUserDefault), then just simply take it out to filter/use for both

In your example, all the contacts is contained within `ContactView` class, either you have to move the `name` and `number` array outside of that class, or the `DialerView` have to hold an instance of the `ContactView` to access them, easiest way is create a singleton to hold that 2 arrays

Comment: oh. I didn't know there was something called a singleton in swift. Just read about it. Implementation seems a bit confusing (probably because i'm new to it)
I'll look into it more. Thanks a lot!